# Как узнать прошел ли месяц с даты регистрации?

Tags: php, sql

Не так давно занялся изучением php + sql и решил сразу перейти к практике.

Создал админ панель где у пользователя admin формируется табличка со всеми пользователями (которые прошли регистрацию) и придумываю разные манипуляции.

В данном случае  вопрос следующий: как узнать **прошел ли месяц с даты регистрации**?

в БД имеются поля:

> ```
> ID
> login
> password
> reg_date
> ```

Comment: Ваш вопрос: «Как сравнить дату регистрации пользователя с текущей датой и выяснить истёк ли один месяц»? Не нашёл вопроса в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @vp_arth вопрос следующий: как узнать прошел ли месяц с даты регистрации

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на функцию [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,reg_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as months FROM users;
```

[Демонстрация](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uwiCd5GQS3BbQdaa7PokGL/2)